# What are reasons to pass getActivity as the LifecycleOwner to the LiveData's observe method in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

This Google sample calls `observe` on `LiveData` in a `fragment` and passes `getActivity()` as the `LifecycleOwner`.

```
mSeekBarViewModel.seekbarValue.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer value) {
            if (value != null) {
                mSeekBar.setProgress(value);
            }
        }
    });
```

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/lifecycles/step5_solution/Fragment_step5.java

I can't wrap my head around any reasons to do that. I only want updates as long as the `fragment` is active, so why not scope it to the `fragment`?
Are there any reasons to ever NOT scope it to the `fragment`?

Comment: IMHO, that's probably a bug in the code lab. "Are there any reasons to ever NOT scope it to the fragment?" -- sure, if you're not in a fragment. :-)

Comment: So you agree that there is no point in scoping LiveData to the activity?

Comment: In this particular case, yes. My guess is that because they are using a shared `ViewModel`, which they obtained using `getActivity()`, that they set up the observer using `getActivity()` as well. In many circumstances, what they are doing probably actually works, but it is a code smell in my mind.

Comment: But is there EVER a reason to do that?

Comment: I can't think of any. However, "EVER" is quite expansive, and so I can't rule it out.

Answer (score 17):

In this case, the Fragment is inflated from a `<fragment>` tag in the Activity's layout, so the lifecycle of the Fragment and the Activity is always the same so it doesn't make any difference.

However, there are two cases where this fails badly:

- If you `remove()` or `replace()` the Fragment, using `getActivity()` for your `LifecycleOwner` will result in leaking the Fragment since the LiveData holds a strong reference to the Observer (and hence, the Fragment since it is a non-static inner class) until the Activity is destroyed
- If you `detach()` and then `attach()` the Fragment (such as with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`), then using the Fragment's lifecycle in `onCreateView()` will result in multiple Observers since `onCreateView()` is called each time the Fragment's view is recreated upon attach and previous Observers are not destroyed since the Fragment's lifecycle has not been destroyed.

The correct `LifecycleOwner` to use in `onCreateView()` is **always** [`getViewLifecycleOwner()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getviewlifecycleowner) since this lifecycle is destroyed when the Fragment's View is destroyed:

```
mSeekBarViewModel.seekbarValue.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer value) {
        if (value != null) {
            mSeekBar.setProgress(value);
        }
    }
});
```

This prevents leaking the Fragment by using a potentially longer lifespan `LifecycleOwner` (like the Activity) and prevents multiple Observers being registered when using patterns like those employed by `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. Say, is there ever a reason to start observing in `onCreate` (in the fragment)? For me, `onCreateView`/`onActivityCreated` in combination with `getViewLifecycleOwner` seems like the all around solution.

Comment: `getViewLifecycleOwner` can't be called in `onCreate()` (the view and hence its lifecycle doesn't exist yet), so you'd want to pair `getViewLifecycleOwner()` with `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use observe `[getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getviewlifecycleownerlivedata) in `onCreate()` (using the Fragment as the LifecycleOwner for that observe call) - then you'll get a callback whenever the view `LifecycleOwner` changes and can register a view specific observer there. That's more useful for listeners external to the Fragment who can't just use `onViewCreated()` though.

Comment: Is there ever a scenario where I would register the `Observer` in `onCreate` and use `this` as the `LifecycleOwner`? To me it seems that this has only downsides

Comment: One side effect of using `getViewLifecycleOwner()` is that you get a callback to your Observer every time the Fragment's view is created (even if the data hasn't changed - you still need a callback to populate the new Views). That isn't necessary or even preferred if your Observer doesn't touch the UI, so you might consider still using `onCreate()` and `this` for those cases.

Comment: Note that `getViewLifecycleOwner()` only exists on the AndroidX edition of `Fragment`, not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Actually, it does exist in the 28.0.0 `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` - the Javadoc on developer.android.com is just not updated

Comment: There's just 1 more uncertainty for me. Is `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` the right place to add a view-scoped `Observer`? Or maybe `onViewCreated`?

Comment: `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated()` are both equally valid (I personally prefer to have `onCreateView()` always just be a one-liner `inflate` call and have my logic in `onViewCreated()`, but YMMV). `onActivityCreated()` suffers the same problem as `onCreate()` and shouldn't be used with a view-scoped Observer.

Comment: But `onActivityCreated` is called directly after `onCreateView` or am I missing something?

Comment: There's a super minor edge case regarding Fragments inflated from a layout (i.e., a `<fragment>` tag where you may get calls to `onViewCreated()` but not `onActivityCreated()`, but you're right that in the vast majority of times, that would also be safe to use.

Comment: So in your previous comment, you were mistaken about `onActivityCreated`? I just want to make sure that I understand it correctly.

Comment: Actually, if I call `observe` in `onCreate` and then replace the fragment (and add it back to the container), I completely stop getting updates from the `LiveData` in this fragment.

Comment: Since you know a lot about `LiveData`, maybe you can take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130047/fragment-not-receiving-livedata-updates-after-remove-add

Comment: Might be interesting to read. It is also referring to this question:
https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb

Comment: Interesting info. I remember early day, based on the tutorial, I was using Fragment itself as live data observer. Later, I realize there are some weird behavior (observer being triggered multiple times), which I need to workaround by first `removeObservers(Fragment)` before I `observe(Fragment)`. So, now to official guideline is using `getViewLifecycleOwner`?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - or register your observers in `onCreate()`, which is only called once

Comment: @ianhanniballake My gold reference source so far is "Lyla Fujiwara's presentation in India 17". I guess, info may a bit outdated. The reason I do not observe in `onCreate` is that, view during that time is not ready. So, I feel it might not make sense to start observing. Is observing using Fragment still fine (As I have a lot of legacy code doing so, not sure I need to revise them and change to getViewLifecycleOwner?)? As long as they are not (1) Part of FragmentPagerAdapter (2) Retained(true) fragment ?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - LiveData only gives you results when you are started, at which time the view is already created - that's why it is fine to start observing in `onCreate()`. Being put on the back stack is the other case where `onCreateView()`/`onViewCreated()` will be called multiple times for the same Fragment instance.