# Fragment not receiving LiveData updates after remove + add

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am currently playing around to get a hang of the `fragment`'s lifecycle in relation to `ViewModel` and `LiveData`.

I have 2 `fragments`, `fragmentA` and `fragmentB`.
I add the `Observer` in the `onCreate` method of each `fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    sharedViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(CharSequence charSequence) {
            editText.setText(charSequence);
        }
    });
}
```

Each `fragment` has a button that changes `LiveData` in the shared `ViewModel`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sharedViewModel.setText(editText.getText());
        }
    });

    [...]
}
```

`SharedViewModel`:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> text = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setText(CharSequence input) {
        text.setValue(input);
    }

    public LiveData<CharSequence> getText() {
    return text;
    }
}
```

When I click a button, I replace the `fragment` for the other one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container_a, fragmentA)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void switchToA(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentA)
                .commit();
    }

    public void switchToB(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

`Replace` causes the `fragment` to be fully destroyed and run through it's `onCreate` method again the next time it is added. I can confirm that `onCreate` is called for each `fragment` placed onto the screen and the `Observer` is added.
But once I replaced a `fragment` and re-added it, it completely stops getting any updates in `onChanged`. Even the ones it sent itself. `onChanged` is just not triggered anymore. I don't understand why.

**Edit:**

I actually found out that the followig `if` check in the `LiveData` class returns the **2nd time** I try to add the `Observer` (after replacing the `fragment` for the first one):

```
@MainThread
public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {
    assertMainThread("observe");
    if (owner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == DESTROYED) {
        // ignore
        return;
    }
```

Hence, the `Observer` is not added anymore. Why does `getCurrentState()` return `DESTROYED` when I try to re-add the `fragment`?

**In short: the `Observer` is removed when the `fragment` is removed, but it doesn't add another `Observer` the next time the fragment is added.**

Answer (score 5):

As per the [Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#destroyed):

> After this event, this Lifecycle will not dispatch any more events.

I.e., `DESTROYED` is a terminal state and once it is destroyed, that Lifecycle will always be destroyed.

This means there are two correct ways to do what you want:

1. Create a new Fragment instance each time you call `switchToA` or `switchToB`. Since all the state is destroyed when you remove a Fragment, you aren't gaining anything by reusing Fragment instances.
2. Don't use `replace`, but instead use `attach()` and `detach()` (i.e., attach the one you want to display, detach the one you want to hide). Fragments keep their state when detached (they aren't destroyed), so re-attaching it will move it back to resumed.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess with a ViewModel there is no need in reusing a Fragment instance that was removed anymore, since we update the new instance with the most recent data anyways?

Comment: When you destroy a Fragment, its ViewModel is destroyed as well, so that's certainly a downside of option #1. If you go with option #1, it may make more sense for these to be Activity scoped ViewModels which wouldn't be destroyed when the Fragment is destroyed

Comment: Right, I actually use an activity scoped ViewModel in the question. But once a fragment went through onDestroy, we always have to create a new instance like you explain in `1.`, right?

Comment: Ah, missed that you were using an Activity scoped ViewModel. In that case, yes option 1 would work perfectly.

Comment: But is this a bug? I feel like if the fragment went through onCreate again, it's lifecycle should be "revived"

Comment: Yeah, I think creating a new Lifecycle instance makes a lot of sense if you want to [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964).

Comment: Actually, I checked it further with some log messages, and `getCurrentLifecyle` returns `RESUMED` after adding the first fragment back to the container. This is so confusing.

Comment: You should check the Lifecycle.State in onCreate() since that's when you are registering your Observer

Comment: Good idea! The first time I add the fragment, it has the state INITIALIZED in onCreate. After removing and adding it, it has DESTROYED in onCreate, but CREATED in onCreateView. Does this mean onCreate is too early to add an Observer when "reviving" the fragment? Unless you create a new instance with new Fragment()

Comment: Seems like a bug to me - it should be consistent whether the first time through or second. Using a new Fragment is a good workaround for right now

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you, that was a nice little quest!

Comment: Please do file a bug